# Mean value and STD with FFT

Tags: fft

currently I'm measuring an oscillator with a laser vibrometer. The oscillator is excited with a shaker and a burst chirp. The vibrometer's output is the time signal of measured point on the oscillator. I then use matlab and fft() to get the spectrum.

My goal is:
Characterizing the oscillator with the peak amplitude and it's corresponding frequency (mean value, STD, confidence interval). For the amplitude I can use the Gaussian distribution.

But how can I characterize the frequency (mean value/STD)? The FFT discretizes the signal with the bins. My oscillator's resonance frequency is usually in the same bin for 100 measurments. It Rarely jumps one bin left or right in those 100 measurements. If I apply the Gaussian distribution my STD would be 0.

My question is:
What else can I use? How would you characterize the resonance frequency?

Comment: Have you looked at super-res algorithms such as [MUSIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSIC_(algorithm))?

Comment: Not yet, thank you!